# Zigzag traversal, c++, Runtime error : Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT), bad memory allocation

Tags: c++

Zigzag traversal, c++, Runtime error : Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT), bad memory allocation

```
class Solution {
public:
    void solve(Node* root, vector<int>& v, int i)
    {
        if (root == NULL) {
            return;
        }
        stack<Node*> ms;
        stack<Node*> cs;
        ms.push(root);

        while (ms.empty() == false) {
            Node* curr = ms.top();
            ms.pop();
            v.push_back(curr->data);
            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                if (curr->left != NULL) {
                    cs.push(root->left);
                }
                if (curr->right != NULL) {
                    cs.push(root->right);
                }
            }
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                if (curr->right != NULL) {
                    cs.push(root->right);
                }
                if (curr->left != NULL) {
                    cs.push(root->left);
                }
            }

            if (ms.empty()) {
                cs.swap(ms);

                ++i;
            }
        }
    }

    //Function to store the zig zag order traversal of tree in a list.
    vector<int> zigZagTraversal(Node* root)
    {
        // Code here
        vector<int> v;
        int i = 1;
        solve(root, v, i);
        return v;
    }
};
```

The code is giving run time error as ,
Runtime error : Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT).
I am not able to find the mistake , pls help me out.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Please provide more details. Also, have you tried to debug at all?

Comment: Create a proper [mre], with the failing "input" hard-coded into the program. Then build and [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) locally on your own system.

Comment: @kiner_shah  The code is not getting executed on VS Code, it is showing as bad memory allocation. The code is supposed to traverse the binary tree, in zig-zag pattern.

Comment: the way to find the mistake is to compile the code, fix compiler errors, then write tests, make all tests pass, then use a debugger. step 1 fails already https://godbolt.org/z/jTWbPxMYW

Comment: *I am not able to find the mistake* -- You wrote the code, you have the test case, so there is no excuse why you can't find the mistake (by debugging) to see where in your code it goes against what you expect.  *How* to fix the error is a different story, but at the very least, you should figure out *where* your code is not doing what you expect.  Remember, *you* wrote the code.

Comment: `v.push_back(curr->data);` -- What if `curr` is `nullptr`?  You would be dereferencing a null pointer, which leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie For smaller inputs it is working, but for large inputs it is not even getting compiled, showing as bad memory allocation.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't think curr can be null at this point.

Comment: @user21141068 *but for large inputs it is not even getting compiled,* -- What do you mean by "not even getting compiled"?  If the program runs, it has already been "compiled".  It is just that your program has a bug you haven't discovered, and it probably doesn't matter how large the input is.  You just haven't found the test case where it fails.

Comment: @user21141068  The bug may be in another part of the code.  Like, for example, where you insert nodes to the tree.  That's a very common point of errors for trees.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie curr will  be a nullptr only in the case ms.empty() == true , the loop breaks in this case.

Comment: @user21141068 -- Please post a [mcve].  First, it is not clear what "zigzag" is supposed to denote.  Second, we don't have a `main` program with test data.  You were given [this link](https://godbolt.org/z/jTWbPxMYW).  That is the state of the code you have given us -- see the errors?  Go to that link, fix the errors, add a `main`, and post the code here.

Comment: *curr will be a nullptr only in the case ms.empty() == true , the loop breaks in this case.* -- I see no verification of this in the code you posted.  You assumed this, but have you verified it?  Maybe possibly: `if (!curr) { cout << "I messed up"; }` right after you get the top item?  All I see is accessing `curr` as if it is valid, and I have no idea what it could be.  Given the runtime error, and what little code you posted, that is one logical conclusion as to why the program will crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next time you post, please do what the others suggested:

- explain what the code is expected to do;
- create an MVP;
- try to debug locally;

### Your problem is this:

You have an infinite loop, because you're always adding the children of the root, rather than the children of the current node.

### Your solution is this:

`cs.push(root->left);` should be `cs.push(curr->left);` in all four places. (Replace left with right, where appropriate.)

### To avoid next time:

Use full words as variable names, like `current`, instead of `curr`. Then you'll be less likely to mix it up with something that looks similar, like `root`.

Naming is one of the hardest problems, and it leads to many mistakes like the one you had.

Comment: Thank you, I am new here, I will be clear from next time.

Comment: Of course, I forgot to say, welcome to Stack Overflow :)